# How to do a function inside another function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this JS Code

```
function toggleMenu() {
    if(!showMenu) {
        hamburger.classList.add('open');
        nav.classList.add('open');
        menuNav.classList.add('open')
        //navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('open'));
        showMenu = true;

    } else {
        hamburger.classList.remove('open');
        nav.classList.remove('open');
        menuNav.classList.remove('open');
        //navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('open'));
        showMenu = false;
    }
}
```

I need to make a function for this 2 lines: `navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('open'));` and `navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('open'));` without using '=>' cause my uglify cant compress this syntax.

Any advices ?

Comment: 1) your `uglify` must be quite obsolete, and 2) just declare a `function` in the other function. You don't have to use `=>`, you can use traditional `function` syntax.

Comment: So something like `navItems.forEach(function(item) { item.classList.add('open');});`

Answer (score 0):

The `function` keyword can be used as both a statement and an expression. Replace the arrow syntax with something like this: `function(item) { return item.classList.add('open') }`